# Is my hiragana/katakana handwriting good or understandable?

Tags: katakana, hiragana, learning, handwriting

[image]

I just started learning Japanese a few days ago.. so far in the process, do you think that my writing is good or easy to read? I am trying to learn, on my own, the hiragana and katakana characters at the same time.

Comment: け looks a little too hooked; almost like しナ.  Also, make sure your ア doesn't curve in too much, or it might be confused with マ.

Comment: @istrasci I heard that comments are not for answers.

Comment: @Leebo: Touché...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only real issue is that your ク looks a bit like カ, everything else is legible.